# Failed to run the mvn goals through shell script

Tags: bash, shell, maven, jenkins

I have below piece of code which will run the mvn goals through bash scripts in jenkins "Execute Shell".

```
 bash -c $M2_HOME/bin/mvn -f $WORKSPACE/pom.xml compile -Dmaven.repo.local=$WORKSPACE/.repository --settings/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/settings-amazon.xml
```

Tried below format but no luck:

```
 bash -c $M2_HOME/bin/mvn compile -f $WORKSPACE/pom.xml  - Dmaven.repo.local=$WORKSPACE/.repository -- settings/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/settings-amazon.xm`l
```

**Exception:**

> [ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify
>   a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format :
>   or :[:]:.
>   Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize,
>   generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources,
>   process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources,
>   process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources,
>   test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package,
>   pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify,
>   install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site,
>   post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]

Comment: You have a space ` - Dmaven...` you should change it to `-Dmaven.repo..` ...?

Comment: jenkins will already run a shell process for you, you don't need to type the `bash -c` in the jesnkins configuration textarea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't have [default goal](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/configuring_default_goal_in_maven), if you want to define it in pom.xml:

> ```
> <build>
> <defaultGoal>clean install</defaultGoal>
> </build>
> ```

If not, add to mvn command the goal you want as :

```
  mvn clean install -f
```